# How can I put my fieldsets side-by-side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

would like to put fieldSets side-by-side on my “Edit” page because I have so many fields on the page.  Since I couldn’t find an easy fix, I decided to put the fields in a table.  This worked fine except for when I click on the “Save” button I get this error:

“Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.”

Questions: How can I put my fieldsets side-by-side or make my table to work with the save button?

Thanks for any help.

Here's the edit methods of my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
      CourseProgress courseprogress = db.CourseProgresses.Find(id);
      ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "Name", courseprogress.CourseId);
      ViewBag.TeacherId = new SelectList(db.Teachers, "TeacherId", "Name", courseprogress.TeacherId);
      var PdfReportProperties = new PdfReport();

        return View(courseprogress);
    }

    //
    // POST: /ProgressManager/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(CourseProgress courseprogress)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(courseprogress).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("ProgressRecord");
        }
        ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "Name", courseprogress.CourseId);
        ViewBag.TeacherId = new SelectList(db.Teachers, "TeacherId", "Name", courseprogress.TeacherId);

        return View(courseprogress);
    }
```

Comment: The error you are getting has nothing to do with putting fields side-by-side in a table. What you are getting is an "Optimistic Concurrency Exception." We will need to see your controller code to help find out what is causing this.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late with this--here's my controller:

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner... rushing my project...not good. I've added the edit method of the controller to the original message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason you are getting that error is that as you don't have a field for the ID of your model in the form, once you hit the SAVE button, the object you are editting has its ID property in null.

To solve it, use a hidden field holding the ID of the model, so that once the form post its fields it became mapped in your controller model object.

This problem has nothing to do with the position or layout of your fields.

Comment: Thanks the hidden ID field was all that was needed.